# Como adicionar um elemento dentro de outro

Tags: javascript

O que eu estou fazendo de errado no meu exemplo?

```js
var t = document.querySelector("#t");

t.prependChild('<div class="verde"></div>');
```

```css
#t{
  width: 300px;
  background: red;
 height: 300px; 
}
.verde{
   background: green;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display: block; 
}
.roxo{
   background: purple;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display: block; 
}
```

```html
<div id="t">
  <div class="roxo"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: O método prependChild não existe, isso é que está errado.

Comment: Como faço para dar certo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Há algumas formas de adicionar um elemento/código HTML dentro, fora, antes ou depois de um elemento. Uma delas é com o método `insertAdjacentHTML`. Com ele você pode usar um código HTML, sem necessidade do `createElement`.

```
element.insertAdjacentHTML("posição", "código-html");
```

Para controlar onde você quer o elemento, basta adicionar um dos valores abaixo no lugar de *posição*

> **beforebegin:** Antes do Elemento

> **afterbegin:** Dentro do elemento e antes do seu primeiro filho

> **beforeend:** Dentro do elemento e depois do seu último filho

> **afterend:** Após o elemento

**Exemplo:**

```js
var t = document.querySelector("#t");

t.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', '<div class="verde"></div>');
```

```css
#t{
  width: 300px;
  background: red;
 height: 300px; 
}
.verde{
   background: green;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display: block; 
}
.roxo{
   background: purple;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display: block; 
}
```

```html
<div id="t">
  <div class="roxo"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: lol, eu não conhecia o `insertAdjacentHTML`

Comment: Tragam um mito para esse Oscar chamado Valdeir. Show de bola esse insertAdjacentHTML.

Answer (score 1):

Duas coisas que você fez errado:

1. Tentar usar um método `prependChild` que não existe
2. Tentar passar uma string para esse método.

#### Solução mais curta

```
var t = document.querySelector("#t");
t.innerHTML = '<div class="verde"></div>' + t.innerHTML;
```

#### Solução sem innerHTML (costuma ser mais eficiente)

```
var t = document.querySelector("#t");
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.className = 'verde';
t.insertBefore(div, t.firstChild);
```

Answer (score 1):

O método `prependChild` não existe, ao menos não nativamente.

Você pode criar o seu próprio método como uma extensão de `Element.prototype`:

```js
var t = document.querySelector("#t");
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.classList.add("verde");


//Espera receber um nó como parâmetro
Element.prototype.prependChild = function prependChild(element) {
    this.insertBefore(element,this.firstChild); 
};


t.prependChild(div);
```

```css
#t{
  width: 300px;
  background: red;
 height: 300px; 
}
.verde{
   background: green;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display: block; 
}
.roxo{
   background: purple;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display: block; 
}
```

```html
<div id="t">
  <div class="roxo"></div>
</div>
```