# Como fazer <?php echo $i ?> ser aleatório entre Y e X?

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress

Estou desenvolvendo um layout, preciso que seus class no div, sejam aleatorios entre dois nomes, preciso de um javascript para fazer isso, alguém pode me ajudar?

Ex.:

```
<div class="left"><div>
<div class="right"><div>
<div class="left"><div>
<div class="right"><div>
<div class="left"><div>
<div class="right"><div>
```

obs.: Lembrando que preciso de uma função 
para inserir, pois vou utilizar isso no Wordpress...

Obrigado

Comment: Vc está fazendo loop no PHP? Se sim, então é melhor usar o PHP para isso do que JS

Comment: Sim, em php, pelo wordpress...

Comment: Precisa de JS pra isso não. Faz no próprio PHP

Comment: Mostre como está fazendo o looping?

Comment: é um loop de conteúdo simples.. de conteúdo de postagem do WordPress

Comment: Vc quer "aleatório" ou "alternando"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exemplificando com um looping `while`, que pode ser aplicado a qualquer outro.

Antes do looping defina o valor `$i = 'left';` e pode usar `<?=$i?>` em vez de `<?php echo $i ?>` se seu servidor estiver configurado para aceitar:

```
<?php
$i = 'left';
while(condição):
?>
<div class="<?=$i?>">conteúdo da div</div>
<?php
   $i = $i == "left" ? "right" : "left";
endwhile;
?>
```

Coloque `$i = $i == "left" ? "right" : "left";` no final do looping, que irá alternando o valor de `$i` a cada volta.

Comment: Esse quase deu Certo, esta com o Loop, eu já tenho o loop, precisava apenas da parte para inserir no loop, consegue me ajudar por favor?

Comment: Sim. O que vc precisa?

Comment: Cara, consegui... muito obrigado... coloquei "$i = $i == "left" ? "right" : "left";" no final do meu loop, e o comando deu certo... Muito obrigado amigo..

Answer (score 2):

Além da forma da citada, há uma outra forma também que é verificando se um determinado número é par ou ímpar, por exemplo:

**PHP:**

```
<?php

for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    /**
     * Caso o número seja par, define a classe como `right`;
     * Caso contrário, define como `left`.
     */
    $class = ($i % 2) ? 'right' : 'left';

    /**
     * Imprime a `div` com a classe e adiciona uma quebra
     * de linha com PHP_EOL
     */
    echo "<div class=\"{$class}\"><div>", PHP_EOL;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```js
const container = document.querySelector("#container");

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  container.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<div class="${i % 2 ? 'right' : 'left'}"><div>`);
}
```

```css
#container {columns: 2}
.left,.right {height: 50px;width: 50px}
.left {background:red}
.right {background:yellow}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

> Para mais informações sobre [insertAdjacentHTML](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/288315/99718)